Keycloak refresh token in K8s Invalid token issuer from internal network
I have a standard microservice-based application running in K8s. Thers is a API gateway that is handling the communication between components.
There is a Keycloak deployed that should authenticate users using OAuth2.
Frontend is ReactJS application that is primarily communicating with the backend. And backend is Spring Boot app that has configured OAuth2 provider as Keycloak.
Let's say that the application is available on https://myapp.mydomain.com. When the user is authentication, the access_token and refresh_token are stored. The iss field of the tokens is https://myapp.mydomain.com/realms/MYREALM.
The communication from frontend works, because the API gateway forward headers like X-Forwarded-Host, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Scheme, etc. And the Keycloak, although running on keycloak-service:8080, can dynamically update information.
So far, so good.
The problem is, when the backend would like to refresh token. The token URL is different from what is recorded in iss field, because the backend is communicating internally inside the K8s with the Keycloak service on http://keycloak-service:8080. And because of that, I always get error Could not refresh token: [invalid_grant] Invalid token issuer. Expected 'https://myapp.mydomain.com/realms/MYREALM'.
I am using Keycloak version 24.0.2 using quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2-0 image.
And the variables are configured to allow dynamic resolving of the host to work on the frontend:
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT
          value: 'false'
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS
          value: 'false'
        - name: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
          value: '-Djgroups.dns.query=keycloak-service-headless'
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: edge
        - name: KC_HTTP_PORT
          value: '8080'
        - name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: 'true'


I was trying to use various combinations of the Keycloak setup, including using KC_HOSTNAME, KC_FRONTEND_URL, using the Frontend URL in realm settings, or combination of issuer names. Nothing works. And the backend does not dynamically creates X-Forwarded headers that can be used in a similar way like communication coming from frontend through the API gateway.
The only way how to make it work is to let the communication through the DNS configured records and set the token URL on the same domain, i.e. https://myapp.mydomain.com/realms/MYREALM/protocol/openid-connect/token instead of http://keycloak-service:8080/realms/MYREALM/protocol/openid-connect/token.
This is fine, however, I do not want to route the communication outside the K8s and then back to inside the K8s for the Keycloak service. It creates latency and cloud costs that should not be necessary when both services are running in the same namespace.
Anyone with experience how to configure this properly to make it work from frontend running in browser and backend using internal K8s service names?

This is something that I too have faced and haven't been able to get the exact working means for it.
